# Excel formula for a dynamic counter based on user defined intervals

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to create a simple spreadsheet that tracks the arrival and departure times for a freight train. Specifically, I have two variables - a) VarA - total time spent by a train on the platform, say 20 hours and b) VarB - total time interval between trains, say 50 hours. If I have hours listed in column A (say midnight Jan 1 through 11pm Dec 31), I want to create a counter in column B that gives me for each hour a '1' if there's a train on the platform, and '0' if there isn't. In this particular case, the two variables would give me 20 '1's and then 50 '0's. This pattern would repeat for all hours in the year.

Request: I want to create a formula (not a VBA code) that takes the two variables as user inputs such that the 1 and 0's change automatically based on the values specified by the user.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share an example and the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Office 365 we can use MOD and SQUENCE and it will spill the results:

```
=--(MOD(SEQUENCE(365*24,,0),B1+B2)<B1)
```

[image]

Older versions than office 365 we need to put:

```
=--(MOD(ROW(A1)-1,$B$1+$B$2)<$B$1)
```

In the first cell.  Then copy/drag the formula down for the number of hours desired for output.

[image]